# jQuery select boxes with same options depending on each other

Tags: jquery, select

For example:
I have 3 select boxes with option values 1-10 in each of them. if I select the value 3 in one of them I need the others to disable 8-10.

i tried this but it's not working correctly:

```
    Select 1: <select name="sel1">
  <option value="0">select</option>
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
  <option value="3">3</option>
  <option value="4">4</option>
  <option value="5">5</option>
  <option value="6">6</option>
  <option value="7">7</option>
  <option value="8">8</option>
  <option value="9">9</option>
  <option value="10">10</option>
</select>
<br>Select 2:
<select name="sel1">
  <option value="0">select</option>
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
  <option value="3">3</option>
  <option value="4">4</option>
  <option value="5">5</option>
  <option value="6">6</option>
  <option value="7">7</option>
  <option value="8">8</option>
  <option value="9">9</option>
  <option value="10">10</option>
</select>
<br>Select 3:
<select name="sel1">
  <option value="0">select</option>
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
  <option value="3">3</option>
  <option value="4">4</option>
  <option value="5">5</option>
  <option value="6">6</option>
  <option value="7">7</option>
  <option value="8">8</option>
  <option value="9">9</option>
  <option value="10">10</option>
</select>
var oldval =0;
var newval =0;
var x=10;

jQuery('select[name^="sel"]').each(function() {
    var thisfahrt = jQuery(this).attr('name');

    jQuery(this).change(function() {
        var ges = 0;
        jQuery('select[name^="sel"]').each(function() {
            if(jQuery(this).val() > 0) {
                ges += parseInt(jQuery(this).val());
            }
        });
        maxval =  x-ges;

        jQuery('option').each(function() {
            if(jQuery(this).parent().val() > 0) {
                if(jQuery(this).val() > jQuery(this).parent().val()) {
                    jQuery(this).attr('disabled', true);
                } else {
                    jQuery(this).attr('disabled', false);
                }
            } else {                                                  
                if(jQuery(this).val() > maxval) {
                    jQuery(this).attr('disabled', true);
                } else {
                    jQuery(this).attr('disabled', false);
                }
            }
        });
    });

});
```

Here my [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/qoyoLoop/).
Maybe somebody have a better and working solution for this?

thank you

Comment: Your fiddle seems to do what you describe. What's the issue with it?

Comment: You should use `.prop()` to manipulate properties like _disabled_

Comment: Well, the code works just as fine as you wanted